# Calculating Proration Percentage in Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I have a SaaS app with Bronze, Silver, Gold plans billed monthly. Each plan has a certain number of credit allotments -- let's say, 10, 25, 50.

Using Stripe default proration behavior, if a client upgrades their plan in the middle of the month, they will be instantly upgraded. They will pay the % bill difference the [next month](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations).

I have a webhook setup for plan changed:

```
if event['data']['object'] == 'customer.subscription.updated':
```

I am looking to calculate how many credits I should give the user. So if they switch from Bronze to Gold halfway through the month, they should get `(1 - .5) * 50 = 25` credit allotment. If they switch one week into the month, they should get `(1 - .25) * 50 = ~37` credits.

Is there a variable that stripe sends in their webhook that would be the ".5" or the ".25", letting me know what percentage of the plan to fulfill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use period start and end, as well as the current webhook time, to calculate the % remaining. I am surprised this is not a Stripe default variable.

Here is an example notebook answer -- take the start time, end time, and the update time to calculate the percentage of time on the plan remaining.

```
current_period_end =  1574401972 # Plan ends 
current_period_start = 1571723572 # Plan starts
plan_updated = 1571769818 # Plan changed

period_length = current_period_end - current_period_start
period_used = plan_updated - current_period_start
print(period_used / 3600 / 24, 'days of', period_length / 3600 / 24, 'days')
period_remaining_pct = 1 - (period_used / period_length)
print(int(period_remaining_pct * 100), '% remaining')
```

In Stripe, inside the `customer.subscription.updated` webhook listener:

```
import time

if event['type'] == 'customer.subscription.updated':

        # Get time params
        session = event['data']['object']
        current_period_end = session['current_period_end']
        current_period_start = session['current_period_start']
        plan_updated = time.time()

        # Calculate remaining time on plan
        period_length = current_period_end - current_period_start
        period_used = plan_updated - current_period_start
        print(period_used / 3600 / 24, 'days of', period_length / 3600 / 24, 'days')
        period_remaining_pct = 1 - (period_used / period_length)
        print(int(period_remaining_pct * 100), '% remaining')
```

From there, it's dependent on your app, but in this example it would be `credits_to_give = period_remaining_pct * 50`

Comment: P.S. Untested in production -- if someone has a better answer -- or if this could raise errors -- please edit.